# Procedure to update mysql database every night to run .sql file stored in a shared drive location

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, stored-functions

I am working with a guy who takes backup of few tables of database everyday from some other system and put .sql file in our shared drive. I need to create a procedure or something that can help me run that file/query every night so I have updated database everyday.

I am using mysql workbench so just want to know if it is possible or please suggest a better way to manage this, may be I can ask him to just extract updates somehow and I can run update query or something.

As of right now it's taking 30 mins or so just to update everyday the whole dump of those tables even though few lines may have changed and obviously the size of those tables are also increasing.

thank you in advance

so far I am just running the query dump .sql everyday to get new data

no error

Comment: You could potentially schedule a script that automatically runs the query. Does this table happen to have some sort of "last updated" column you can use to filter its operation?

Comment: If you have enterprise version, Incremental backup will do the job. So that when restoring only the changes will be added.

Comment: @James how to setup incremental backup in the workbench. I think that would work for me.

Comment: @tshimkus how to schedule it, I would like to try. As of now I just go and select from file menu to import sql script so I would like to really know as I am fairly new to the workbench. You can also email me or give me an example here. thank you

Comment: How you schedule the script depends on your server OS. Apache, nginx, and IIS will all have different methods. There are so many different ways you can execute the stored procedure but MYSQL Workbench isn't the right utility for that

Comment: It could be a bash or batch script from the scheduler or you could have the scheduler call an external script (PHP, python, ruby, etc.)

Comment: which software is more suitable for this. should I get PHPMyAdmin for this?

Comment: @tshimkus can you suggest?

Comment: If it's Linux use crontab. For Windows Server use Windows Task Scheduler.